# Can we query the value based on the result of the another value in Redis without the Network around?

Tags: redis

Suppose there are two key value pairs in the Redis. one's key is key1 ,and value is value1, another key is value1, and value value2 ,that means the first one's value is just another's key , now I want to get the value2.
So I get query the key1 to get the value1, then I used the value1 to get the value2, however there are two network trips , what I needed is just one network trip,such as when we get the value1, it wouldn't return to the client intermittently, but continue query the value2 based on the key value1, then return after that.

Answer (score 1):

No, Redis does not have a built-in dereferencing mechanism.

A Lua script appears to be a good approach, but taking it would violate the Redis directive for explicitly passing it all key names. This could be addressed if the original requirements are changed slightly - use a single Hash key to store all the values and pass that key's name to the script. Note that unless dereferencing is constant (e.g. always performed once), you'll need to differentiate between values that need dereferencing and values that don't - that can be done, for example, by prefixing "pointer" values with a special character.

Comment: Could you please give more details on *Redis directive for explicitly passing it all key names*? Or at least give me a link? I've no idea on this directive before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tsk, tsk. Someone didn't RTFM ;) check the first section, Introduction to EVAL, at http://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: I only find the following: *All the additional arguments should not represent key names and can be accessed by Lua using the ARGV global variable* and *All Redis commands must be analyzed before execution to determine which keys the command will operate on. In order for this to be true for EVAL, keys must be passed explicitly.*

Comment: It doesn't forbid passing key names to lua script. The lua scripting solution doesn't pass the key name as a member of `ARGV` array, but pass it into the `KEYS` array. I don't think there's any problem with this solution. Please correct me, if I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: `value1` a.k.a. `real_key` isn't given explicitly, but rather generated programmatically by reading data